# Acts 1 & 2 were more than the Apostles baptized in the Holy Spirit?

Tags: history

**All** the personal pronouns appear to refer to the apostles, so were they the only ones baptized in the Holy Spirit? Note Acts 1:26 and Acts 2:1.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gu1WZXxgVE3DRu4x_hzORq-43fcwK8apYbYyLZQycNg/edit

Answer (score 2):

I believe the text tells us that there were more than Apostles who were overcome with the Holy Spirit. Chapter 1 tells us that there were 120 disciples in the upper room. In Acts chapter 2, the text tells us that the Holy Spirit filled the whole house were they were sitting. Since we know that chapter breaks are man made, we would understand that the upper room is in the house where they were sitting.

Acts 1:12-15 (KJV)

> 12 Then returned they unto Jerusalem from the mount called Olivet,
>   which is from Jerusalem a sabbath day's journey. 13 And when they were
>   come in, they went up into an upper room, where abode both Peter, and
>   James, and John, and Andrew, Philip, and Thomas, Bartholomew, and
>   Matthew, James the son of Alphaeus, and Simon Zelotes, and Judas the
>   brother of James. 14 These all continued with one accord in prayer and
>   supplication, with the women, and Mary the mother of Jesus, and with
>   his brethren. 15 And in those days Peter stood up in the midst of the
>   disciples, and said, (the number of names together were about an
>   hundred and twenty,)

Acts 2:1-4 (KJV)

> And when the day of Pentecost was fully come, they were all with one
>   accord in one place. 2 And suddenly there came a sound from heaven as
>   of a rushing mighty wind, and it filled all the house where they were
>   sitting. 3 And there appeared unto them cloven tongues like as of
>   fire, and it sat upon each of them. 4 And they were all filled with
>   the Holy Ghost, and began to speak with other tongues, as the Spirit
>   gave them utterance.

Acts 2:8-11 provides a list of countries where the visitors to Jerusalem heard the 120 speaking in tongues, ie, the language wherein they were born. You'll notice the list is longer than 12, indicating more than 12 languages were spoken.

Acts 2: 8-11 (KJV):

> 8 And how hear we every man in our own tongue, wherein we were born? 9
>   Parthians, and Medes, and Elamites, and the dwellers in Mesopotamia,
>   and in Judaea, and Cappadocia, in Pontus, and Asia, 10 Phrygia, and
>   Pamphylia, in Egypt, and in the parts of Libya about Cyrene, and
>   strangers of Rome, Jews and proselytes, 11 Cretes and Arabians, we do
>   hear them speak in our tongues the wonderful works of God.

In addition, the prophecy from Joel, indicates that women were to be included in the movement of the Holy Spirit. Note the reference to daughters and handmaidens.

Acts 2:14-18

> 14 But Peter, standing up with the eleven, lifted up his voice, and
>   said unto them, Ye men of Judaea, and all ye that dwell at Jerusalem,
>   be this known unto you, and hearken to my words: 15 For these are not
>   drunken, as ye suppose, seeing it is but the third hour of the day. 16
>   But this is that which was spoken by the prophet Joel; 17 And it shall
>   come to pass in the last days, saith God, I will pour out of my Spirit
>   upon all flesh: and your sons and your daughters shall prophesy, and
>   your young men shall see visions, and your old men shall dream dreams:
>   18 And on my servants and on my handmaidens I will pour out in those
>   days of my Spirit; and they shall prophesy:

Comment: Thanks for a reply; but did you consult the link where all the personal pronouns are colored lavender? I think the same question about putting forward names to be voted on by lots had to have been conducted only by the apostles themselves. There's no question all the apostles were (most think) in the upper room where the sound filled the house where they were sitting. HOW can we include the 120 being baptized in the Holy Spirit? I do not see how. Please look at that link and see if you find anything I've missed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not following the argument here.  Is it that the 120 could not have all fit in the upper room?

Comment: @ Don Wood I don't understand, the context is clear. As a minimum, chapter 1 verse 14 states that the women and Jesus' brothers were with the apostles. Further, that chapter 2 says the "all were filled with the Holy Ghost". I think it's real stretch to say that all the pronouns exclusively tie to the apostles, especially when the context is telling you that "they" refers to the 120. The account of the selecting of Mathias was in the midst of the entire gathering that's why chapter 1 verse 26 says that he was numbered with the 11 apostles, ie to differentiate between the 120 and the 12.

Comment: I agree with @alb.  I cannot see any exclusivity here.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Don Wood See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

More were baptized:-

> Acts 2:40, 41  NWT  And with many other words he gave a thorough witness and kept exhorting them, saying: “Get saved from this crooked generation.” 41 So those who gladly accepted his word were baptized, and on that day about ***3,000*** people were added.